# Android Espresso : How to match grand parent? without giving exact hierarchy

Tags: android, android-espresso

```
onView(allOf(
        withText(activityUnderTest), 
        withParent(withId(R.id.llh_root_record_activity_3_item))))
    .check(matches(anything())) ;
```

In above code snippet `withParent` matcher is failing because view id given is not immediate parent but grand parent.

It can be handled as below, but curious to know the trick,specially when you don't want to specify messy  hierarchy as used in below code.

```
onView(allOf(
        withText(activityUnderTest), 
        withParent(withParent(withParent(withId(R.id.llh_root_record_activity_3_item))))))
    .check(matches(anything())) ;
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

isDescendantOfA is what you need.
Actually, it doesn't apply to grand parent only.
Please check [espresso cheat sheet](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/cheat-sheet)

```
onView(allOf(withText(activityUnderTest), isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.llh_root_record_activity_3_item))))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: @TanajiPadwal https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/cheat-sheet